# json2view like solution for iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, random

For Android I see there is a very good solution Json2View:

https://github.com/Avocarrot/json2view

for creating Android app UI on the fly. Is there any similar solution available for iOS? Is there any constraint is having JSON based UI concept for iOS, the way json2view does for Android? Or best would be some common open source library that has flavor for both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Using **React Native** you can accomplish the same. 
Strictly speaking, its not Json to View but its **JavaScript to View**.

Whatever views you create in ReactJS, will be created using native UIKit Framework. 

For example, if you use scrollview component in JS, it will use a scrollview subclassed of UIScrollView.

Please check this link for in-depth overview

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/823

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do anything like this, you will get apple rejected because of using any kind of  code injection.